# Brand new to LC3

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am trying to write a program that will accept a user input and print the binary form of that input.  I am using the getc trap for the input.  I know that the getc input will be stored in R0 so I am thinking in need to use a BRzp then AND each bit to output either 1 or 0.  Can someone tell me if im thinking in the right direction.

PS I have to output the binary code in a string.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

> I am using the getc trap for the input.

If you are using GETC in order get a character, you should put a PUTC right after if you want to have the input echoed on the screen.

> I am thinking in need to use a BRzp

BR is a conditional branch. Unless you want the PC to branch to a different part of your code, you shouldn't be using it.

> then AND each bit

AND is a boolean algebra function. 0101 AND 0011 would be 0001.

PUTC or PUTS (for strings) are used in order to display an ASCII character to the console.

Before you tackle any coding in LC3, I would recommend you read up on what each psudo-code and psudo-op does and how LC3 functions before tackling your problem.

This slide is a good starting point. It shows you basically everything you need to know before coding in Assembly: https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmpe012/Winter09/lectures/06_LC3_Assembly.pdf

Appendix from the Intro to Computing Systems textbook: http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/dl/free/0072467509/104691/pat67509_appa.pdf